# 2d array from boost::multi_array - unable to compile

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-multi-array

I am trying to create a 2d array class based on `boost::multi_array`. I face two issues in the code given below. (1) The code for the member function `col()` does not compile saying that `::type’ has not been declared`. Where am I going wrong? (2) Is it possible to define the member function `data()` outside the class? My attempt gives compile error as the typedefs are not available. But I am unable to define the typedefs outside the class  because the typedefs in turn require the type `T` which is available only inside the template class. Thanks.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
class Array2d{
public:
    typedef typename boost::multi_array<T,2> array_type;
    typedef typename array_type::element element;
    typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;

    //is it possible to define this function outside the class?
    Array2d(uint rows, uint cols);
    element * data(){return array.data();}

    //this function does not compile
    template<class Itr>
    void col(int x, Itr itr){
        //copies column x to the given container - the line below DOES NOT COMPILE
         array_type::array_view<1>::type myview  = array[boost::indices[range()][x]];
         std::copy(myview.begin(),myview.end(),itr);
    }

private:
    array_type array;

    uint rows;
    uint cols;
};

template <class T>
Array2d<T>::Array2d(uint _rows, uint _cols):rows(_rows),cols(_cols){
    array.resize(boost::extents[rows][cols]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_type::array_view<1>::type
```

You need template and typename here :)

```
typename array_type::template array_view<1>::type
^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^
```

The keyword template is required because otherwise the < and > will be treated as less and greater because the array_type is a dependent name, and therefore whether array_view is a nested template or not is not known until instantiation.

Comment: I had figured out with the help of compiler error message and the input from K-ballo. But why the `template` requirement?

Comment: @suresh : For more details, see this FAQ: [What is the `->template`, `.template` and `::template` syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix)

Answer (score 1):

> (1) The code for the member function col() does not compile saying that ::type’ has not been declared.

`array_type` is a dependant type on `T` and `array_type::array_view<1>::type` is still dependant on `T`, you need a `typename`.

> (2) Is it possible to define the member function data() outside the class?

It sure is, but it shouldn't be a problem for it to be defined inside the class.

```
 template< typename T >
 typename Array2d< T >::element* Array2d< T >::data(){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the problem line as `typename array_type::template array_view<1>::type  myview  = array[boost::indices[range()][x]];` and it compiled. But then, why this explicit mention of `template` is required? The compiler suggested it though. (gcc 4.4.3)

Comment: @suresh: Because is a dependent template; dependant types need `typename` and dependent templates need `template` keywords.